# Python se salta IF

Tags: python, python-3.x

Mi programa basa en realizar una simple calculadora no es el mejor codigo eso ya se sabe pero al intentar ejecutar el primer if con un 1 llega a saltaro y aprovechando de su valioso tiempo (si asi fuera) que puedan correguirme en algun otro aspecto en el codigo(OPCIONAL :D) gracias por leerlo.
pd: apenas me enganche con python 3.

```
print ('Que operacion desea realizar :\n 1.SUMA \n 2.RESTA \n 3.MULTIPLICACION \n 4.DIVISION \n 5.MODULO')
Numero = input()
if Numero==1:
print ('Ingrese el primer numero :')
Numero1= input()
print ('Ingrese el segundo numero :')
Numero2= input()
print ('El resultado es :',RSuma)
```

Comment: Eso es todo D: solamente que ingresando 1 se salta el if y no hace nada.

Comment: Hola lambda, cuando lees con el input el valor es un `string` y tu en el if lo comparas con un `int` . Para solucionar tu problema entre otras cosas puedes poner `if Numero=="1":`

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda <3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observaciones:

- Esta mal indentado<sup>1</sup> tu código, pues tanto las líneas de `print` y las variables `Numero1` y `Numero2` existen dentro del contexto del condicional `if`
- Los valores que recibes a través de los `input` debes castearlos a enteros en este caso de este modo: `int(input())`, pues por defecto los lee como `string`<sup>2</sup>
  La indicación anterior del cast  a los `inputs` va también para el primero de la variable `Numero`

Tu código (incluyendo para pruebas la variable `RSuma` creo debería verse así):

```
print ('Que operacion desea realizar :\n 1.SUMA \n 2.RESTA \n 3.MULTIPLICACION \n 4.DIVISION \n 5.MODULO')
Numero = int(input())
if Numero==1:
  print('Ingrese el primer numero :')
  Numero1= int(input())
  print('Ingrese el segundo numero :')
  Numero2= int(input())
  RSuma = Numero1 + Numero2
  print('El resultado es :',RSuma)
```

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup>[indentación](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=indentation)
- <sup>2</sup>[inputs python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

Comment: Gracias lo tomare en cuenta hoy en adelante saludos.